# Update Quantity to subtract 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Update product.tblproductinformation 
SET Quantity = (Quantity-1) 
where(Select iProduct.ProductID 
      from tblindividualproduct as iProduct 
      INNER JOIN tblproductinformation as pInfo ON iProduct.Code = pInfo.Code) = @p1"
```

i want to update my quantity to subtract 1. I also included inner join because my where is in another table. i got an error:

`You cant specify target table 'tblproductinformation' for update in FROM clause`

what's wrong?

Comment: "*What's wrong*"?  What's wrong is that you can't specify the target table for update, `tblproductinformation`, in the FROM clause of your subquery.

Comment: Even if you could, there's no correlation to the outer `tblproductinformation` so it probably wouldn't achieve what you want.  Also the subquery might return multiple results, which would give rise to another error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join the tables directly:

```
UPDATE tblproductinformation AS pInfo
  JOIN tblindividualproduct  AS iProduct ON iProduct.Code = pInfo.Code
SET    pInfo.Quantity = pInfo.Quantity - 1
WHERE  iProduct.ProductID = @p1
```